# How to join a table after another join?

Tags: sql, join

Hallo, I was trying to join the table after the another join table. My expected output is to have all the code in CODE1, CODE2, and CODE3 are shown just like the table below:

```
channel_division_group staff_id the_code total update_dt
---------------------- -------- -------- ----- ---------
CH3                    101      CODE1    1     03-Mar-11
CH3                    101      CODE1    1     03-Mar-11
CH3                    101      CODE2    1     03-Mar-11
CH3                    101      CODE3    1     03-Mar-11
```

But the actual result is the row with CODE3 was missing:

```
channel_division_group staff_id the_code total update_dt
---------------------- -------- -------- ----- ---------
CH3                    101      CODE1    1     03-Mar-11
CH3                    101      CODE1    1     03-Mar-11
CH3                    101      CODE2    1     03-Mar-11
```

Here is source code for your reference:

```
    select channel_division_group, staff_id, the_code, total, update_dt
    from (
        select 'CODE1' the_code from dual
        union all
        select 'CODE2' the_code from dual
        union all
        select 'CODE3' the_code from dual
    )
    left outer join (
        select a.staff_id, a.code, update_dt, 
            case when m.update_dt is null then 0
                      else count(*)
            end total,
            case a.channel_division_group
                when 'CH1' then 'CH1'
                when 'CH2' then 'CH2'
                else 'CH3'
            end tableC
        from (
            select code, staff.staff_id, staff.channel_division_group
            from (
                select 'CODE1' code, '1' seq from dual
                union all
                select 'CODE2' code, '2' seq from dual
                union all
                select 'CODE3' code, '3' seq from dual
            ), code_staff staff
        ) a
        left outer join tableM m
        on a.code = m.decision and to_char(a.staff_id)=m.approval_id
        group by a.staff_id, a.code, update_dt, a.channel_division_group
        order by a.channel_division_group, a.staff_id
    ) app
    on the_code=app.code and staff_id=app.staff_id
    where update_dt between trunc(to_date('13-MAR-11'), 'MONTH') and trunc(to_date('13-MAR-11'))
    group by channel_division_group, staff_id, the_code, total, update_dt
    order by staff_id;
```

If I remove the where clause statement, the CODE3 will be shown but this doesn't filter within the date. Is this could be done when a join after another join together with the where clause?

THanks @!

Answer (score 1):

you going complex join better to use "with statement" for sql join like below.

```
with
   temp_t1 as (
               select dummy c1 from dual
              )
  ,temp_t2 as (
               select dummy c1 from dual
              )
select *
from temp_t1 a
    ,temp_t2 b
```

Its help you.